# Generated test code for JVM Test Suite source set not marked as 'generated test sources root' in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jvm-test-suite

I have a Gradle Java project using [Google AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/main/value/userguide/index.md) to generate value classes. The project also applies Gradle's [JVM Test Suite plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html) and has a test suite for 'component tests'. This results in a new source set with directories `src/componentTest/java` and `src/componentTest/resources`.

AutoValue classes created in the `src/main` and `src/test` source sets work as expected. However, AutoValue classes in `src/componentTest/java` result in a compilation error in IntelliJ:

[image: Compilation error in AutoValue class]

This is because the generated class cannot resolve the source class (`ComponentTestPojo`):

[image: Cannot resolve symbol error in generated class]

I believe the problem is because IntelliJ is not marking the `generated-test-sources-for-test-suite/app/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/componentTest` folder as a 'generated test sources root'. The corresponding folder for unit tests are marked as such:

[image: Folder structure]

The `.iml` files for the unit and component test modules have a key difference that I believe explains this:

`generated-test-sources-for-test-suite.app.test.iml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module version="4">
  <component name="AdditionalModuleElements">
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../app/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/test">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../app/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/test" isTestSource="true" generated="true" />
    </content>
  </component>
</module>
```

`generated-test-sources-for-test-suite.app.componentTest.iml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module version="4">
  <component name="AdditionalModuleElements">
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../app/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/componentTest">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../app/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/componentTest" isTestSource="false" generated="true" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../app/src/componentTest" dumb="true">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../app/src/componentTest/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../app/src/componentTest/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
    </content>
  </component>
</module>
```

Note that in the unit test file, the `sourceFolder` for the generated code path has `isTestSource="true"` whereas the component test file has `isTestSource="false"`. If I manually change this to true, everything works as expected. However I cannot figure out how to rectify this in the `build.gradle`. Manual changes will be reverted when the project is reloaded.

It is worth noting that the project builds fine from the terminal when invoking `./gradlew clean build check` so this is an IntelliJ-specific issue.

What configuration am I missing?

I have created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/stuartleylandcole/generated-test-sources-for-test-suite) with a minimal reproducible example. I have also included the `build.gradle` file below:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details on building Java & JVM projects, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/building_java_projects.html in the Gradle documentation.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin for API and implementation separation.
    id 'java-library'
    id 'jvm-test-suite'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    autoValueVersion = "1.10.4"
}

dependencies {
    compileOnlyApi("com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:${autoValueVersion}")

    annotationProcessor("com.google.auto.value:auto-value:${autoValueVersion}")
}

testing {
    suites {
        // Configure the built-in test suite
        test {
            // Use JUnit Jupiter test framework
            useJUnitJupiter('5.10.0')

            dependencies {
                compileOnly "com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:${autoValueVersion}"

                annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:${autoValueVersion}"
            }
        }

        componentTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            useJUnitJupiter('5.10.0')

            dependencies {
                compileOnly "com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:${autoValueVersion}"

                annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:${autoValueVersion}"
            }

            targets {
                all {
                    testTask.configure {
                        shouldRunAfter(test)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.named('check') {
    dependsOn(testing.suites.componentTest)
}

// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}
```

My AutoValue class is as follows:

```
package com.example;

import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;

@AutoValue
public abstract class ComponentTestPojo {

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_ComponentTestPojo.Builder();
    }

    public abstract String id();

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public static abstract class Builder {

        public abstract Builder id(final String id);

        public abstract ComponentTestPojo build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please report issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: I have created an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-345313/Generated-test-code-for-Gradle-JVM-Test-Suite-source-set-not-marked-as-generated-test-sources-root-in-IntelliJ